# How to integrate Bootstrap Grid System in WordPress

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a custom page with some content.

My issue now is that I'm having problems on styling the page itself. 
I'm used to working with the Bootstrap column system "col-lg-12".
It's simple and fast to work with.

How can I add Bootstrap to WordPress to achieve this?

Comment: What kind of page do you want to style? Admin, Frontend, ...?

Comment: Hi, Philipp, I resolved my problem already. Thanks for reading and posting.

Answer (score 1):

Site visitor-facing part of any WordPress site is handled by a *theme*. Contents of theme (outside of WP conventions for meta information and template structure) are arbitrary.

In other words — anything you can do in HTML you can do in a WordPress theme.

Naturally this includes CSS/HTML frameworks such as Bootstrap and there are multiple existing themes using them out there.

Comment: To be exact I'm using "Themify". Yes, that's a great suggestion but since I coded my custom page, in HTML/php functions I'm not using the attributes of the template. It does style my text by following the parent theme. my exact question should have been. what did people did for a grid system before bootstrap?

Comment: Before Bootstrap people used one of many other frameworks or just custom CSS as they saw fit. :) WP doesn't really care about that part.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Stack community I end up taking this approach for solving my problem!

I downloaded the Bootstrap CSS source files. 
I search on the CCS file for the code of block that controls all the "col-md, col-sm, col-xs, col-lg, as well offsets" and placed that code on my CSS!

now I can use the column grid system on my WP site.
Easy fix, amazing results.